# Trunc Method in Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi

I am porting some code to .Net and I realized that the Trunc method is not properly working in Delphi. It doesn't account whether you are truncating a negative or positive value. It treats the argument as absolute.

Delphi

```
Trunc(-163.78999) returns -163
```

.Net Implementation

```
System.Math.Floor(-163.88888888888889) returns -164.
```

I can mimic the implementation but I am wondering if anyone has seen this before.

Thanks,

Comment: `Trunc` != `Floor`. Which bit of documentation led you to believe that `Trunc` would always round to a lower value, rather than towards zero (which is what truncation usually means)? Note that `Math.Truncate` will behave the same way.

Comment: How about `Math.Truncate`?

Comment: Thanks jon...That was an oversight from my end.

Comment: No worries. That just happens. For typos we have *a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error* close vote reason. [the downvote is not mine, but I'm not voting up either, since I don't think it's good to even keep a question claiming by mistake that *Trunc method is not properly working in Delphi* searchable here]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delphi's [`Trunc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Trunc) function performs as designed. The documentation says (emphasis mine):

> Truncates a real number to an integer.
>
> In Delphi code, the Trunc function truncates a real-type value to an
>   integer-type value. X is a real-type expression. Trunc returns an
>   Int64 value that is **the value of X rounded toward zero**.

The .net equivalent to Delphi `Trunc` is [`Math.Truncate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx).

The Delphi equivalent to .net `System.Math.Floor` is [`Floor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.Floor).

Comment: Thanks...Actually, I was porting the code and I see the previous programmer done a Trunc that rely on System.Math.Floor. 

Things make sense now ...The math is the same. 

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that the name is also quite intuitive: [Truncate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truncate) will simply shorten the value by chopping off the fractional part. It has no need to consider the sign or direction towards zero (rounding _towards zero_ is somewhat coincidental).